# Flutter Bloc Tutorial - How to show user name i.e. value from other page

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/flutterlogintutorial

My code is in GitHub:
Link - https://github.com/mymomisacoder/bloc_login2

For this tutorial, I would like to seek advise on how to add/show the username in the home page (on login).

Intended Input:

> In login page, Login button is pressed after keying in username and password.

Desired Event:

> Screen transit to the home page. Besides having a logout button in home page, username provided earlier is also shown.

I tried 2 methods:

Method 1: create a getusername() in userrepo class

Method 2: assign a value in userrepo class and access via blocprovider

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc =
    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);

    final LoginBloc loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

//method2
    **//String username2 = loginBloc.usernamebloc;

//method1
    String username2 = loginBloc.userRepository.getUserName().toString();**
    print("$username2");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
              child: Text('logout'),
              onPressed: () {
                authenticationBloc.dispatch(LoggedOut());
                },
              ),

              Center(
                child: Text("Hello"),
                **//child: Text("$username2"),**
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

User Repo Class

```
class UserRepository {

  String username1;


  Future<String> authenticate({
    @required String username,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
//method2
    username1 = username;
    return 'token';
  }

  Future<void> deleteToken() async {
    /// delete from keystore/keychain
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return;
  }

  Future<void> persistToken(String token) async {
    /// write to keystore/keychain
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return;
  }

  Future<bool> hasToken() async {
    /// read from keystore/keychain
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return false;
  }

//method1
  **Future<String> getUserName() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return username1;
  }**
}
```

Main Page

```
class SimpleBlocDelegate extends BlocDelegate {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
    print(event);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print(transition);
  }

  @override
  void onError(Bloc bloc, Object error, StackTrace stacktrace) {
    super.onError(bloc, error, stacktrace);
    print(error);
  }
}

void main() {
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  final userRepository = UserRepository();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      builder: (context) {
        return AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository)
          ..dispatch(AppStarted());
      },
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserRepository userRepository;

  App({Key key, @required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationUninitialized) {
            return SplashPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return HomePage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error Code:

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
The following assertion was thrown building HomePage(dirty):
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type LoginBloc.
No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
BlocProvider.of().
 This can happen if:
1. The context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
2. You used MultiBlocProvider and didn't explicity provide the BlocProvider types.

Good: BlocProvider(builder: (context) => LoginBloc())
Bad: BlocProvider(builder: (context) => LoginBloc()).
The context used was: HomePage(dirty)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code here.

Comment: Hi @kiner_shah, thanks you for replying to my question.  I have updated the code above.

I have tried 2 methods to access the method in the login form page;
Method 1: create a getusername() in userrepo class
Method 2: assign a value in userrepo class and access via blocprovider

Comment: Is the username getting printed after successful login? I mean this line `print("$username2");` in `HomePage` class.

Comment: Hi Kiner, the username is not printed for either method.
The error code seems to point to the context.  I have updated the error code in my question above.

Comment: Can you post the code for the parent widgets of `HomePage`? Or can you post the entire widget tree? This error is most likely because you are passing the incorrect `context` to the `BlocProvider`.

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar Hi Sir, i have posted my code in Github.  The URL is  https://github.com/mymomisacoder/bloc_login2

Comment: @kiner_shah thank for offering a bounty.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem by doing the following.

Changed getUserName() method in UserRepository to return String (instead of Future). So, the code looks as below :

```
String getUserName()  {
    return username1;
  }
```

Altered definition of HomePage a bit to accept UserRepository parameter. Now, the definition looks as below :

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;
  HomePage({Key key, @required this.userName})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// ...
```

Finally, commented the login bloc line as IMHO it didn't have anything useful in the overall HomePage code you've written so far. New code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc =
    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);

    //final LoginBloc loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

    //String username2 = loginBloc.usernamebloc;
    String username2 = userName;
    print("$username2");
```

And this works. You'll see the user name in the console window.

Comment: Hi Sukhi.  Thank you for helping to answer.

Comment: Hi Sukhi.  Thank you for helping to answer.  Yes, using key can help to get access to the variable.  However, from my limited knowledge of bloc, this method does not seems to tap on the bloc framework.

Do you think it is possible to use bloc to derive the value of username from the login page?  If so, could you show me how to do so.

Comment: Just to check if you happen to know how to extract the ancestor context?

Comment: I didn't have opportunity to work with Bloc yet. Quickly ran through a couple of tutorials and it led me to think two two are independent from each other i.e. passing the payload directly or via Bloc. As I understand, Bloc is more for event and state management. Experts can correct me if I am wrong. I referred : [Tutorial 1](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-todos-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-d9dd833f9df3), [Tutorial 2](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-pattern-for-dummies-like-me-c22d40f05a56)

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  If no one is able to post a solution tapping on Bloc framework to derive the value by tomorrow, i will mark your answer as accepted (for benefit of those not using bloc).

Separately, i am exploring using multi provider at the login page to provide the value.  You might want to check that out.

Comment: One way of accessing class properties would be to write a specific getters, like you wrote - get UserName(). I don’t know if that’s the best practice in the Bloc world though. Shall soon find out.

Comment: Do let me know when you find out. My guess is a singleton bloc/global bloc

Comment: Anyway I have mark it as best answer. The bounty was from kiner